# cdecl error: expected initializer before

Tags: c++, c, calling-convention, cdecl

I have a problem with the cdecl calling convention:

```
void Test1(char* str, ...)           // ok
{}

void cdecl Test2(char* str, ...)     // error: expected initializer before 'Test2'
{}

int main()
{}
```

What should I do to make the compiler recognize the cdecl calling convention?

Thanks!

Platform: Windows 7; MinGW; GCC 4.6.1

---

I cannot modify those functions, since they are part of "Microsoft Excel Developer's Kit, Version 14", in the file FRAMEWRK.H:

```
///***************************************************************************
// File:        FRAMEWRK.H
//
// Purpose:     Header file for Framework library
//
// Platform:    Microsoft Windows
//...
// From the Microsoft Excel Developer's Kit, Version 14
// Copyright (c) 1997 - 2010 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
///***************************************************************************
...
// 
// Function prototypes
//

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void far cdecl debugPrintf(LPSTR lpFormat, ...);
LPSTR GetTempMemory(size_t cBytes);
void FreeAllTempMemory(void);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Note: this answer (and all answers similar to it) is technically incorrect, as the comments below indicate. I am not removing it, so that we do not lose the comments. (**END EDIT**)

Prepend it with two underscores, like this: `__cdecl`

Comment: The problem is that that function is part of the "Microsoft Excel Developer's Kit, Version 14" (FRAMEWRK.H). I think I should not be supposed to modify it.

Comment: In that case, I think that FRAMEWRK.H was meant to be used with MSVC, not GCC. See if you can put something like `#define cdecl __cdecl` before including the header file. But I'm afraid that this is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @MrLister: you were right both about `#define cdecl __cdecl` and about the iceberg... Now I get errors about undeclared functions (e.g. `memcpy_s`) that are declared; they are global, included and path are set.

Comment: @PietroM I am afraid that if you are working so closely with Microsoft technologies, then a Microsoft Compiler is the way to go.

Comment: @MikeNakis: you are right. With a Microsoft compiler these issue are resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the default calling convention for C and C++ programs. Place the __cdecl modifier before a variable or a function name

The compiler is instructed to use C naming and calling conventions for the system function:

```
// Example of the __cdecl keyword
_CRTIMP int __cdecl system(const char *);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271989%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) for documentation of cdecl in Microsoft.

Comment: If you're going to copy code, you should also state the source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks(v=vs.71).aspx